# Two divs, one fixed width, the other, the rest

Tags: css, html

I've got two div containers.

Whilst one needs to be a specific width, I need to adjust it, so that, the other div takes up the rest of the space. Is there any way I can do this?

```css
.left {
    float: left;
    width: 83%;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    min-height: 50px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    overflow: auto;
}

.right {
    float: right;
    width: 16%;
    text-align: right;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    min-height: 50px;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="left"></div>
<div class="right"></div> <!-- needs to be 250px -->
```

Comment: Don't use decade-old hacks for ancient browsers. Scroll down for modern flexbox solution.

Comment: Before you follow Evgeny's link consider the browsers your users actually use, rather than the browsers you wished they used. Flexbox is not going to render nicely on your professor's IE 9: https://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox

Comment: @duhaime IE9 has 0.13% global usage

Comment: So 1 out of 1000 users...

Answer (score 132, accepted):

**See:** http://jsfiddle.net/SpSjL/ *(adjust the browser's width)*

**HTML:**

```
<div class="right"></div>
<div class="left"></div>
```

**CSS:**

```css
.left {
    overflow: hidden;
    min-height: 50px;
    border: 2px dashed #f0f;
}

.right {
    float: right;
    width: 250px;
    min-height: 50px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    border: 2px dashed #00f;
}
```

---

You can also do it with `display: table`, which is usually a better approach: [How can I put an input element on the same line as its label?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6938900/how-can-i-put-an-input-element-on-the-same-line-as-its-label/6938990#6938990)

Comment: It's not working with me. Left is going at 100% width and right is 250px. Two lines :(

Comment: You need to swap the order of the `div`s, like in my answer and my demo. `right` then `left`.

Comment: Overall this works for me but sometimes when I have text in the left div instead of wrapping to the next line (and there is space) it is just cut off on the right (where the right div starts). How can I make the text wrap in the left div?

Comment: Not floating DIV fills the full width. Bad idea when content is higher than floating DIV or text too long.

Answer (score 64):

It's 2017 and the best way to do it is by using flexbox, which is [IE10+ compatible](http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox).

```css
.box {
  display: flex;
}

.left {
  flex: 1;  /* grow */
  border: 1px dashed #f0f;
}

.right {
  flex: 0 0 250px; /* do not grow, do not shrink, start at 250px */
  border: 1px dashed #00f;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div class="left">Left</div>
  <div class="right">Right 250px</div>
</div>
```

Comment: your comment on the question saved me from trying to support IE6.  thanks!

Comment: This is also good, but  calc() is much better than flex due to the compatibility with IE9 and Chrome 26.

Comment: This worked well for me. Didn't even need the .right width to be defined.

Comment: It kills me that in 2017/2018/2019 we still get comments along the lines of BEWARE OF IE 9.

Comment: You can set the width of the right div to auto as well, like "flex: 0 0 auto;".

Comment: Thanks, this is the answer which worked for me.

Answer (score 49):

You can use calc() Function of CSS.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/A8zLY/543/

```
<div class="left"></div>
<div class="right"></div>

.left {
height:200px;
width:calc(100% - 200px);
background:blue;
float:left;
}

.right {
width:200px;
height:200px;
background:red;
float:right;   
}
```

Hope this will help you!!

Comment: thanks for the advice. I checked the compatibility among browsers, and [it's kind of high for stable usage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc#Browser_compatibility)

Comment: This should be selected as the best answer, because in this answer the DIV tags ain't swapped like in the best answer.

Comment: helpful even with other flexbox solutions, in my case due to incompatability of flex box in a certain nesting of a react library / component, cheers.

Comment: Why have I only just discovered `calc`!?

Answer (score 15):

If you can flip the order in the source code, you can do it like this:

HTML:

```
<div class="right"></div> // needs to be 250px    
<div class="left"></div>
```

CSS:

```
.right {
  width: 250px;
  float: right;
}
```

An example: http://jsfiddle.net/blineberry/VHcPT/

Add a container and you can do it with your current source code order and absolute positioning:

HTML:

```
<div id="container">
  <div class="left"></div>
  <div class="right"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#container {
  /* set a width %, ems, px, whatever */
  position: relative;
}

.left {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 250px;
}

.right {
  position: absolute;
  background: red;
  width: 250px;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

Here, the `.left` div gets an implicitly set width from the `top`, `left`, and `right` styles that allows it to fill the remaining space in `#container`.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/blineberry/VHcPT/3/

Comment: FIrst example doesn't seem to actually work.  The .left div in the jsFiddle is actually the full width of the screen.  If both divs are the same height then great, but in this case just add 5px padding to .left and you'll see.

Comment: The second solution worked great for me though.  Genius!

Answer (score 6):

If you can wrap them in a container `<div>` you could use positioning to make the left `<div>` anchored at `left:0;right:250px`, see [**this demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/FQxkq/1/). I'll say now that this will not work in IE6 as only one corner of a `<div>` can be absolutely positioned on a page ([see here](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/conflictingabsolutepositions) for full explanation).

Answer (score 3):

1- Have a wrapper div, set the padding and margin as you like
2- Make the left side div the width you need and make it float left
3- Set the right side div margin equal to the left side width

```
.left
{
    ***width:300px;***
    float: left;
    overflow:hidden;

}

.right
{
    overflow: visible;
    ***margin-left:300px;***
}



<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="left">
        ...
    </div>

    <div class="right" >
        ...
    </div>

</div>
```

Hope this works for you!

Answer (score 1):

There are quite a few ways to accomplish, negative margins is one of my favorites:

http://www.alistapart.com/articles/negativemargins/

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

set your right to the specific width and float it, on your left just set the margin-right to 250px

```
.left {
vertical-align: middle;
min-height: 50px;
margin-right: 250px;
overflow: auto
```

}

```
.right {
width:250px;
text-align: right;
display: table-cell;
vertical-align: middle;
min-height: 50px;
height: 100%;
overflow: auto
}
```

Comment: kill the display type in .right and make sure you dont have a clear setting anywhere that would be affecting .left

Comment: do you have any kind of wrapper div?  Is there something online i can go inspect or is this totally local?

Comment: It's completely, local, however, let me try to put it on jsfiddle.

Comment: haha, you removed your float: right.  Also, don't forget to account for border widths, so if you are going to leave those in subtract the widths from one of the div widths.

Answer (score 1):

If you need a cross browser solution, you can use my approach, clear and easy.

```
.left{
        position: absolute;
        height: 150px;
        width:150px;
        background: red;
        overflow: hidden;
        float:left;
}
.right{
        position:relative;
        height: 150px;
        width:100%;
        background: red;
        margin-left:150px;
        background: green;
        float:right;
}
```