# Make div take remaining width

Tags: html, css

I have the following code

```html
<div style="float:left;height:16px; background:grey; width:200px;"></div>
<div style="float:left;height:16px; background:lightblue; width:100px;"></div>
```

Is it possible to make second div take all the remaining width without using tables?

Here is JSFiddle for clarification 
http://jsfiddle.net/xtkoycyv/

Comment: Use % instead of px?

Comment: I think you are looking for the `display` propperty. (` display:table;`)

Comment: Here's another solution to go with the other answers - http://stackoverflow.com/a/6487192/3377049 here's a fiddle I did that fits yours better.. http://jsfiddle.net/Hastig/SpSjL/2881/

Answer (score 4):

yes it is... Remove the float from the second div

```html
<div style="float:left;height:16px; background:grey; width:200px;">this text</div>
<div style="height:16px; background:lightblue;">that text</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I have noticed that it works already by only removing float:left.

Comment: lol, you are absolutely correct!!! a div is a block element so will be 100% width by definition. I've updated my answer.

Comment: @Aaron: This doesn't actually work. This simply makes the appearance of working. The floated element is simply 'sat on top' of the other element, hiding the "lightblue" div behind it.

Comment: @jbutler483 not sure it is mate, it's floated not absolute positioned? added copy to my answer to show it's working.

Comment: @Aaron: It works in that respect, But take a look at [this](http://jsfiddle.net/jqL3t30z/1/) - it might clear up a few things. since floating elements takes it out of the dom, it makes the other div behave differently. This is why floats would be used as a last resource, as its mechanics can be difficult to follow at the best of times.

Comment: @jbutler483 is he needing to show a hover state then?

Comment: @Aaron: I am **not** presuming that are, I am merely pointing out that whilst this may appear to (visually) work, behind the scenes the floated element is "sat on top of" the other (full width) div. Maybe include a clarification or explanation as to why this 'works'?

Comment: @jbutler483 OK, I see what you're saying... not sure it's that relevant to what the OP is looking to achieve here though.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `calc()` property available in CSS3

```html
<div style="float:left;height:16px; background:grey; width:200px;"></div>
<div style="float:left;height:16px; background:lightblue; width:calc(100% - 200px);"></div>
```

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/efyvfp6o/)**

Comment: No idea how I've missed knowing about calc until just now. Margin play will be much easier now.

Comment: Is it safe to use calc?

Comment: http://caniuse.com/#feat=calc - known issues. Seems to be 3 things to keep in mind, at least. IE related, of course.

Comment: @ZeroCool Yes. You can definitely use it.

Answer (score 1):

## Using Calc

There are a couple of different solution to this. One of which would be to use the calc function.

> The calc() function allows mathematical expressions with addition
>   (‘+’), subtraction (‘-’), multiplication (‘*’), and division (‘/’) to
>   be used as component values. The ‘calc()’ expression represents the
>   result of the mathematical calculation it contains, using standard
>   operator precedence rules. It can be used wherever ,
>   , , , , or  values are
>   allowed. Components of a ‘calc()’ expression can be literal values,
>   ‘attr()’ or ‘calc()’ expressions, or  values that resolve
>   to one of the preceding types.

```css
.div1 {
  height: 16px;
  background: grey;
  width: 200px;
  float: left;
}
.div2 {
  height: 16px;
  float: left;
  background: lightblue;
  width: calc(100% - 200px);
}
```

```html
<div class="div1"></div>
<div class="div2"></div>
```

## Using Display:Table

You could also use the `display: table` option. *note: this is not using tables*

```css
.wrap {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
}
.div1 {
  height: 16px;
  background: grey;
  width: 200px;
  display: table-cell;
}
.div2 {
  height: 16px;
  background: lightblue;
  display: table-cell;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="div1"></div>
  <div class="div2"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use calc(100%-1st div)

Div1 - 20%
Div2 - 80%

In case if u need to use the remaining width jus use % or  jquery function to calculate its width

using script

```
 $(document).ready(function()
 {
     var div1 = $("div1").width();
     var div2 = (100%) - (div1+'px');
     $(div2).css('width',div2);
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `%` instead of `px` and remove `float:left` from second div
Here is the code:

```
<div style="float:left;height:16px; background:grey; width:200px;"></div>
<div style="height:16px; background:lightblue; width:100%;"></div>
```

Comment: looks like a duplicate of my answer :)